# How to insert text in a range of row in a specific column in a csv file in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to insert a text in a range of lines in a specific column of a csv file like [2:], I already searched other questions like this on the internet, but none worked for me.

Example:

"File before I insert text"

```
NAME, AGE
 , 2
 , 3
 , 4
 , 5
```

"File after I insert a text"

```
NAME, AGE
 , 2
henrique , 3
henrique , 4
 , 5
```

My code:

```
header = ["Name", "Age"]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=header)
var=df.shape[0]
df.loc[2:, 'Name'] = 'henrique'
df.to_csv("stackoverflow.csv", sep=',
          index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html

To insert data you want to use `df.at(2:, 'Name')`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=header)
var=df.shape[0]
df.at(2:, 'Name') = 'henrique'
df.to_csv("stackoverflow.csv", sep=',
          index=False)
```

However, if you want the following output

```
NAME, AGE
 , 2
henrique , 3
henrique , 4
 , 5
```

Then you should use this index

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=header)
var=df.shape[0]
df.at(1:2, 'Name') = 'henrique'
df.to_csv("stackoverflow.csv", sep=',
          index=False)
```

Comment: I used the above code and wanted to add a that instead of the parentheses use square brackets here as in df.at[1:2, 'Name'] = 'henrique'